# Виртуализация окон Windows на Ubuntu

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ubuntu

Здравствуйте.

Мне совершенно не нужен рабочий стол Windows в Ubuntu, не хочу ставить VirtualBox.
Я хочу просто окна, примерно так, как могут Parallels и VMWare на Mac'ах.
Можно ли как нибудь реализовать это на Ubuntu? Гугление не помогло, не знаю как данная фича называется.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Может, Wine?

Comment: Если речь не о full screen приложениях, то wine - именно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Не совсем то. Что не запускал в Wine - везде что-то глобальное вело себя не правильно, из-за чего невозможно было работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы **что-то глобальное** вело себя правильно, то без виртуализации не обойтись.

А в VirtualBox есть seamless mode - окна гостевой системы интегрируются в хостовую. [Вот так.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQr8iI0yZH4)

И в VMware есть Unity mode - не менее красиво: [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDUyil00EqQ), [ещё видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-OF0XP8QXc).

Comment: Большое спасибо, то, что нужно!
Ещё бы мануалов, как это всё настроить... (: